# Append in Python clearing list

Tags: python

I have a piece of code:

```
binCounts = []
for i in range(len(bins)):
    binCounts.append(0)
```

where `bins` is an array that looks something like this:

```
['chrY', '28626328', '3064930174', '28718777', '92449', '49911'], ['chrY', '28718777', '3065022623', '28797881', '79104', '49911'], ['chrY', '28797881', '3065101727', '59373566', '30575685', '49912']]
```

When I run just `range(len(bins))` in Python's interactive mode, I get:

```
[0, 1, 2]
```

but when I test the whole piece of code, I'm getting

```
[0,0,0]
```

I believe I should be getting

```
[0, 1, 2, 0]
```

This is resulting in a Division by Zero error later on down the line. Why is this happening? How can I fix it? I appreciate your guidance!

Comment: What do you think `binCounts.append(0)` does?

Comment: adds a '0' to the end of the list..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are receiving a list of zeros because of this line:

```
binCounts.append(0)
```

Each time through the loop, you append a zero to `binCount`

---

If your goal is to put a zero only at the end of the list, pull that line out of your `for` loop

```
for i in range(len(bins)):
    # Logic
binCounts.append(0)
```

---

It appears you are creating a list with values in the range 0 through the length of `bins`. You can do this without `for` loop:

```
binCounts = range(len(bins))
binCounts.append(0)
```

At the end of these two lines, `binCounts` will be:

```
[0, 1, 2, 0]
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Removing the for loop makes great sense and I appreciate that suggestion. I'm still getting used to the indentation formalities of Python and it seems that's where most of my problems come from. Could you recommend a good text editor that won't slip in false tabs and the like? (I use TextWrangler which is pretty good, but maybe there is something made specifically for Python?)

Comment: Python has a number of [IDEs](https://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratedDevelopmentEnvironments) you can choose from. They range from stand alone applications dedicated to Python development to plugins for Eclipse, Visual studio or others. This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python) is also helpful

Comment: @mfk534, try pycharm - https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/ - even community edition is very good

Answer (score 3):

Your code add 0 to list 3 times, so you are getting exactly what you asked. Maybe you wanted to do:

```
binCounts = []
for i in range(len(bins)):
    binCounts.append(i)
binCounts.append(0)
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I had to put a space between 'binCounts.append(i)' and 'binCounts.append(0)' and then it worked like a charm. I appreciate it.